# how to draw coordinates linear equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

The function $f$ is defined by

$$f(x) =\begin{cases}  -\frac x3 -4/3 & \ -1  \le x<2 \\  3x -8 & 2\le x\le 5 \end{cases}$$

Now I am trying to draw $y= f(x)$

I started by mapping out the $x$ and $y$ like this

- $x=-1, y=-1$
- $x=0, y=-4/3$
- $x=1, y=-5/3$
- $x=2, y=-2$
- $x=3, y=1$
- $x=4, y=4$
- $x=5, y=7$

And all I have to do is draw the line to the points right ?
I am asking because I was confused by the two conditions and Want to confirm that I am doing it right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part is defined by the segment

- left point: $\left(-1,-1\right)$
- right point: $\left(2,-2\right)$

and the second part is defined by the segment

- left point: $\left(2,-2\right)$
- right point: $\left(5,7\right)$

Comment: I edited the arguments to how they should be dont know why it got messed up

Comment: @zellez Ah ok, indeed I had some doubts on that. I fix accordingly.

Comment: So my answer was ok ? And it is just as I said right you draw the function $f(x)$ with the points I mapped

Comment: @zellez Yes that's right, not that we need only three points to draw the graph.